# Split single row into multiple rows on the basis of begdate and enddate?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Problem Table t1**

```
ID  BegDate EndDate 
1   01-01-2020  01-07-2021  
2   01-01-2020  01-02-2021  
3   01-01-2020  01-12-2021
```

I need to split table t1 records into month wise in SQL Server 12 Below is the example for ID=1

```
ID  OLD_ID  NewBegDate  NewEndDate
1   1   01-01-2020  31-01-2020
2   1   01-02-2020  29-02-2020
3   1   01-03-2020  31-03-2020
4   1   01-04-2020  30-04-2020
5   1   01-05-2020  31-05-2020
6   1   01-06-2020  30-06-2020
7   1   01-07-2020  31-07-2020
8   1   01-08-2020  31-08-2020
9   1   01-09-2020  30-09-2020
10  1   01-10-2020  31-10-2020
11  1   01-11-2020  30-11-2020
12  1   01-12-2020  31-12-2020
13  1   01-01-2021  31-01-2021
14  1   01-02-2021  20-02-2021
15  1   01-03-2021  31-03-2021
16  1   01-04-2021  30-04-2021
17  1   01-05-2021  31-05-2021
18  1   01-06-2021  30-06-2021
```

Comment: simple way to use `CTE`. Alternatively is to join to a tally / number table

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with a little change in date format. Try this code:

```
SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH,'2020-01-01', '2021-07-01'))
    NewBeginDate =  CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MONTH, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, '2020-01-01')), 
    NewEndDate = EOMONTH(CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MONTH, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, '2020-01-01'))) FROM    sys.all_objects a
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b;
```

You can use any table instead of `sys.all_objects`. I just wanted to make a cross join.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the same for all rows (not only one row), below query shows you the detail.

**Your Sample Data**

```
create table #t1 (ID int, BegDate datetime, EndDate datetime)

insert into #t1 values
(1,  '2020-01-01', '2021-07-01'),
(2,  '2020-01-01', '2021-02-01'),  
(3,  '2020-01-01', '2021-12-01')
```

**Use Tally**

```
declare @base_dt date = '2020-01-01'
;with dts as (
select
    -- this is to generate tally
    rn = (ROW_NUMBER() over (order by object_id))
    , beg_dt = dateadd(month, (ROW_NUMBER() over (order by object_id)) - 1, @base_dt)
    , end_dt = eomonth(dateadd(month, (ROW_NUMBER() over (order by object_id)) - 1, @base_dt))
from sys.objects
)
select dts.rn as ID, #t1.ID as OLD_ID, dts.beg_dt as NewBeginDate, dts.end_dt as NewEndDate
from dts
    inner join #t1 on dts.beg_dt >= #t1.BegDate and dts.end_dt <= #t1.EndDate
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find that a recursive CTE is handy in these situations:

```
with cte as (
      select id, begdate, dateadd(day, -1, enddate) as enddate
      from t
      union all
      select id, dateadd(month, 1, begdate), enddate
      from cte
      where begdate < enddate
     )
select row_number() over (order by id, begdate) as id, id as old_id,
       begdate as newbegdate, eomonth(begdate)
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6a5c5fc21e214ec83774f9f2b6ff76f4) is a db<>fiddle.

The only caveat is that if the periods might exceed 100 months, then you need `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

Comment: Thanks, It worked but for ID=1 there should be 18 rows and in result it shows 19 rows including July 2021 but it should be till 30th june.